# Java: Get ParameterizedType from PropertyDescriptor

Tags: java, reflection, javabeans

#### Problem

I am working on a project where I have to deal a lot with reflections and the performance needs to be improved. This method is called very often and this part seems inefficient to me as I need to get the Field by another reflection, which I only need to compare the type parameters of two Objects (I don't know how inefficient it really is tbh). Because I want List.class != List.

Even finding out whether a Class has type parameter without having to do crazy reflections should be enough.

#### Current situation

The code is just experimental right now and will be cleaned up in the future.

This method basically calls the setter of a PropertyDescriptor with the value of the getter PropertyDescriptor as an Argument this should only happen if their classes are the same, otherwise I treat them differently, however I have run into some issues with Lists, Sets, etc where List is the same as List which should not be the case. That's why I get the ParameterizedType of the Fields to compare their type parameters.

```java
protected boolean translate(S source, T target) {
   Class<?> readPropertyType = getter.getPropertyType();
        Class<?> writePropertyType = setter.getPropertyType();

        Type[] getterTypeParameters = null;
        Type[] setterTypeParameters = null;;

        try {
            ParameterizedType getterParameterizedType = (ParameterizedType) source.getClass()
                .getDeclaredField(getter.getName()).getGenericType();
            getterTypeParameters = getterParameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments();

            ParameterizedType setterParameterizedType = (ParameterizedType) target.getClass()
               .getDeclaredField(setter.getName()).getGenericType();
            setterTypeParameters = setterParameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments();
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | ClassCastException e) {}

        try {
            if (readPropertyType == writePropertyType && Arrays.equals(getterTypeParameters, setterTypeParameters)) {
                setter.getWriteMethod().invoke(target, getter.getReadMethod().invoke(source));

                return true;
            }

            ... Handle other cases
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }

}
```

If you need more context, I made my git public:
https://github.com/RaphaelEckmayr/AnotherJavaAutoMapper/blob/main/src/main/java/net/AJAM/Mapper/BaseTranslation.java

For reference this code takes about 0-1ms. However it is called for almost every field of a class.

#### Edits

More code and description of method added

Comment: Can you add a bit more context about why you are doing this, and what your function actually does?

Comment: @tgdavies Sure, one second

Comment: Hi there. Stackoverflow is usually more about asking questions about code that does not work. For questions related to improving efficiency of code that works, I'd recommend you to post it here instead: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @ShivamPuri I have actually never heard of codereview on stackexchange, thank you. I mean it's half working as it throws around ClassCastExceptions all over the place as sone as there are no type parameters.

Comment: I'd do some actual measurements to make certain that this code is worth speeding up. It looks as though you could cache the result of your first try/catch and the expression in your if statement with a key of source.getClass, target.getClass and the two method names.

Comment: The good thing is that it works most of the time without the extra reflections. On average my entire code takes around 43ms with the reflections and 37ms without them.

Comment: You didn’t ask a question. Besides that, properties are defined in terms of the *public API*, i.e. getter and setter methods. You should not subvert it by assuming that there is a field matching the property name. Fields are an implementation detail. Why don’t you use `getter.getReadMethod().getGenericReturnType()` and `setter.getWriteMethod().getGenericParameterTypes()[0]`? Then, all you’re doing with `getActualTypeArguments()` and comparing them, is not better than `getterParameterizedType.equals(setterParameterizedType)` (which wouldn’t even need a cast to `ParameterizedType`).

Comment: @Holger That's excactly what I was looking for, thank you.

Btw, sorry for not directly asking a question, I thought that a problem description should be sufficient.